# python3: bind method to class instance with .__get__(), it works but why?

Tags: python, methods, python-3.x, monkeypatching, descriptor

I know if you want to add a method to a class instance you can't do a simple assignment like this:

```
>>> def print_var(self): # method to be added
        print(self.var)
>>> class MyClass:
        var = 5
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> c.print_var = print_var
```

this indeed would cause `print_var` to behave like a normal function, so the `self` argument wouldn't have his typical meaning:

```
>>> c.print_var
<function print_var at 0x98e86ec>
>>> c.print_var()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#149>", line 1, in <module>
    c.print_var()
TypeError: print_var() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

In order to let the function be considered a method (i.e. to bind it to the instance), I used to use this code:

```
>>> import types
>>> c.print_var = types.MethodType(print_var, c)
>>> c.print_var
<bound method MyClass.print_var of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x98a1bac>>
>>> c.print_var()
5
```

but I found that `.__get__` may also be used for this purpose:

```
>>> c.print_var = print_var.__get__(c)
>>> c.print_var
<bound method MyClass.print_var of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x98a1bac>>
>>> c.print_var()
5
```

The problem here is that it just works, but I can't understand how and why. The documentation about [`.__get__`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#object.__get__) doesn't seem to help very much.

I'd appreciate if someone could clarify this behaviour of python's interpreter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The information you're looking for is in the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods):

> To support method calls, functions include the `__get__()` method for binding methods during attribute access. This means that all functions are non-data descriptors which return bound or unbound methods depending whether they are invoked from an object or a class. In pure Python, it works like this:

```
class Function(object):
    . . .
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
        return types.MethodType(self, obj)
```

So there really isn't anything strange going on -- the `__get__` method of a function object calls `types.MethodType` and returns the result.

Comment: In Python 3 `MethodType()` only accepts 2 arguments.

Comment: @joeforker I'm quoting from the Python docs there, sounds like they need to be updated.

Comment: In fact they are updated. I recommend you edit the answer

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde um... I followed the link... 3 parameters in the python docs... unless I'm misunderstanding the intention of your comment?

Comment: @drevicko He's not saying `__get__` changed, he's saying `MethodType` takes only two arguments now -- it used to take three. I updated the answer two years ago to reflect that.